# mfrow retains duplicate plots

Tags: r, plot

Below is my simple script for 6 plots of normal, log normal, negative log normal qq plots with their respective histograms. I am using the mfrow function, and I am getting duplicate plots instead of 6 unique plots. I really appreciate if you can direct me to a solution to this issue.

```
y1=rnorm(500,0,1)
y2=rlnorm(500,0,1)
y3=-rlnorm(500,0,1)

par(mfrow=c(3,2))

plot(qqnorm(y1),xlab="Theortical Quantiles", ylab="Sample Quantiles",main="Q-Q Normal")
qqline(y1, col='red')
plot(hist(y1),main="Histogram Normal")

plot(qqnorm(y2),xlab="Theortical Quantiles", ylab="Sample Quantiles",main="Q-Q Log Normal")
qqline(y2, col='red')
plot(hist(y2),main="Histogram Log Normal")

plot(qqnorm(y3),xlab="Theortical Quantiles", ylab="Sample Quantiles",main="Q-Q Negative Log Normal")
qqline(y3, col='red')
plot(hist(y3),main="Histogram Negative Log Normal")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `qqnorm(y, ...)` instead of `plot(qnorm(y), ...)`.